What is the valid value for Webform element type in form-element.html.twig?
I'm currently attempting to rewrite the form-element.html.twig to incorporate custom CSS based on the label display and field type for Webform element output. While I've successfully identified checkbox and radio field types, I'm encountering difficulties with other fields such as files and text fields (document file, image field, text).
I've experimented with various values including 'file', 'document_file', 'image_file', 'text', and 'textfield', but none seem to yield the desired results. What is the valid value for Type in this context?
Here is my sample:
{%
  set classes = [
    'js-form-item',
    'form-item',
    'js-form-type-' ~ type|clean_class,
    'form-type-' ~ type|clean_class,
    'js-form-item-' ~ name|clean_class,
    'form-item-' ~ name|clean_class,
    title_display not in ['after', 'before'] ? 'form-no-label',
    disabled == 'disabled' ? 'form-disabled',
    errors ? 'form-item--error',
    type == 'checkbox' ? 'form-check',
    label_display == 'after' and type not in ['checkbox', 'radio', 'file', 'document_file', 'image_file', 'text', 'textfield'] ? 'MY-CUSTOM-CSS'
  ]
%}

Update:
According to the Element (YAML) source code in the webform settings, the File field type is valued as "managed_file" while the Image field type is designated as "image_file." I tried both values in form-element.html.twig; the "managed_file" works for the File field, and the "image_file" does not work for the Image field.

There are two things you could check. First, the type populates two of the classes in the code you've shown, printed in the HTML source you can open in the browser. Second, if you've found the correct type and it still doesn't work, it could be that the theme you are using has more than one template file for form elements. Activate Twig Debug to see which template is used for which form element.
